# documenting txt files in Doxygen

Tags: python, doxygen

I am using Doxygen to document a Python project. The application uses some small txt files, containing e.g. config info, logs etc. For obvious reasons, no Doxygen information can be included in those files directly (problems with parsing, these files might not exist) - I need to write this doc in other files (containing code).

The problem is, that I can't dox 2 files in one code file (or at least - std doxyconf doesn't allow it - no doc for that minor or nonexistent files is generated)

Do you know, how to overcome it? What specific tweak in conf should be done? Or should I rather create a .py file (same dir as the file in question) which would contain only comments (documentation)?

Thanks in advance.

Edit. Ok ill try to make it clearer. Say i got my code in following files:

```
(...)/project/functions.py
(...)/project/interface.py
(...)/project/data/js/functions.js
```

if running, the app generates some directories:

```
(...)/project/data/gallery/gallery1
(...)/project/data/gallery/gallery2
(...)/project/data/gallery/gallery3
```

in gallery1, we have 3 jpgs and 3xmls, in gallery2 - 1 jpg, gallery3- 5xJPG & 5xXML. All of which - uploaded by the user.
As galleries 1, 2 & 3 have a bit different usage, after creating these dirs, we create also a file:

```
(...)/project/data/gallery/types.info
```

This file contains info in format:

```
gallery1#galleryType1
gallery2#galleryType2
gallery3#galleryType1
```

Note. If the application is idle (the user doesnt do anything), there are no galleries and no types.info file...
Now, i want to create a doxygen entry about this poor types.info, so that it would be visible in files tab. 
The @verbinclude does not work :( 
I added @package tag, and it might be a workaround, but it would really be nice if i had this file documented in Files tab of the doc page...
Clearer? :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but maybe \verbinclude can help to include the txt files into some comment block that further explains them.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the problem, or what you're trying to achieve. Could you include some more details, e.g. Example files and snippets, and what output you want

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to accomplish this with the `@file` attribute in a documentation block, something like:

```
/**
 * @file project/data/gallery/types.info
 * Documentation for types.info in project/data/gallery/.
 */
```

In order for this to work, you'll also need to add `types.info` as a valid doxygen input file name (verify the `INPUT` and `FILE_PATTERNS` doxygen configuration attributes will include it), and the file must exist (but it can be empty).

The main caveat I found with this approach is that it doesn't seem to work with python style doxygen comments:

```
## @file project/data/gallery/types.info
# Documentation for types.info in project/data/gallery/.
```

You'll need to have source file that can contain C/C++ style comments, and that file will also show up under the files tab.